# Confused about using or not using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know the use cases for nested attributes. The pros and cons of using vs. not using it.

I have a model that has a lot of `has_many` associations. Example:

```
class Post
  has_many :visitors
  has_many :pageviews
  has_one  :metric
end
```

Although I like the idea of just sending one request and having all of those things created with the correct associations, I don't like the idea that all the creation of the `visitors`, `pageviews` and `metric` are in the `PostsController`. I very much like the separation of concerns. Is there any clear rule that I should follow when dealing with nested attributes?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? I don't think there is a clear rule like "have a most 3 nested attributes". It depends on how your app is structured, usually I would think the user is also overwhelmed by having to create so many things in one step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In data-modelling we sometimes split up stuff over different tables/models, and imho nested models/nested forms are mostly used where the nested model has no reason to exist without the parent and vice versa. E.g. a person with their addresses: when creating a person we immediately need to add their address because (for instance in a delivery situation) a person without an address makes no sense.

Nested forms, where we can edit parent/child models as a whole, was popular and imho still has its benefit/place in some very specific situations (like the aforementioned example).

But in most cases, where the creation of the parent is not dependant on the child, I rather prefer to use ajax calls. I present all the information on a page, but when adding a child I make sure it is immediately saved and stored in the database (using their own controller --while visiting the parent's show page for instance).

I believe in most cases that the default/standard mega form is not the best UI/UX solution, and I believe that should be the main driver how to build your pages.

Coming back to your example: these should never be shown in one huge form, nobody is going to edit a post, *and* the stats, right? Statistics are collected and shown, but hopefully never "created". Normally one tracks actual pageviews, visitors ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have really grasped what nested attributes is used for in the first place. Its used when you need to CRUD a resource and its children in a single request.

Its use is really dictated by the user experience requirements. Sometimes you actually need a single form like this very common order form example:

```
class Order
  has_many :line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
end

class LineItem
  belongs_to :product
end
```

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:line_items) do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.number_field :quantity %>
    <%= ff.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    if @order.update(order_params)
      # ..
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order)
          .permit(:line_items_attributes: [:quantity, :product_id, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

This is just that common checkout form where users can change the number of products in their cart. It lets the users manipulate multiple records at once in a plain old synchronous form.

That said nested attributes is probably one of the most misused components of Rails though and everything beyond 1 level of nesting usually ends up in a hideous mess. Its also a very common misconception that it should be used to assign associations which should in most cases just by done by adding selects or checkboxes that point to the `_id` or `_ids` attributes created by the associations.

If you are using it just to mosh everything into a single controller because "I don't want to have too many classes. Waaah" then yes its a huge anti-pattern.

The alternative really is using AJAX to let the user CRUD child records without reloading the page.

I would say that your example is not a good candidate for nested attributes. Are any of those associations actually even created by the user?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making a leap you don't need to.

> I don't like the idea that all the creation of the visitors, pageviews and metric are in the PostsController.

They shouldn't be and don't have to be. In fact, they never are by default.

Run `rails routes` in your console and you'll see each of those `has_many` models have their own controllers and views.

It is very rare I have a web app with a model that doesn't have and use its own controller.

A route like `/posts/:id/visitors` should point to `visitors#index`, not something like `posts#visitors`

If you're putting everything into one controller, I'd argue you aren't actually nesting, you're expanding.

And I'd argue the point of relational databases is to have relationships, so limiting your relationships seems kinda self-limiting.